# Stretched textures in exported FBX file

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, .fbx

[image: nodes][image: Here is what it looks like in blender]

[image: here is what it looks like in fbx file]

Please Let me know what am i doing wrong and how to solve it,
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This appears to be a limitation/bug in the FBX exporter.

Comment: Any other way to export my models to fbx perfectly?

Comment: let’s see your node setup.

Comment: Theres nothing in Nodes just a Image texture to base color, Image texture is a baked Diffuse map of a procedural texture.